# powershell winforms context menu

Tags: powershell, .net-framework, winforms

Have the following from [How to add options to mouse-right-click menu in PowerShell forms](https://superuser.com/questions/1273875/how-to-add-options-to-mouse-right-click-menu-in-powershell-forms)

```
$contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("Item 1") | Out-Null
$contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("Item 2") | Out-Null
```

And it is working... I can see the context menu.. but how do
I do something once the menu item has been selected.

Like if a user selects Item 1 how do I know it was selected.

Comment: Add an event handler.

Comment: That's helpful for a beginner/noob like me.

Answer (score 0):

As DavidPostill guidance leads... There loads of videos, articles and sample code that takes on thru this sort of thing, step-by-step. For your query, here is an example of what DavidPostill is saying.

```
$textBox1.Add_Click(
    {    
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Hello World." , "My Dialog Box")
    }
)

$form1.ShowDialog()
```

See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25911.how-to-add-a-powershell-gui-event-handler-part-1.aspx

Comment: Ok, I can follow along with that for a textbox.  But the same applies to the contextmenustrip1 object?  So how I determine which menu item was selected?  is it numbered somehow? 

would I add something like  $contextMenuStrip1.Add_Click?

Comment: @nixgeek You need to learn to walk before you can run. Learn the basics before trying to modify random bits of code you found on the internet.

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to do this... Instead of just adding Context Menus. I also added as David Pointed out the Event Handler.
I replaced:

$contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("Item 1") | Out-Null
$contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("Item 2") | Out-Null

With this:

$contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("Item1", $ContextMenuStripItemImages).add_Click({ MyCode Here })
$contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("Item2", $ContextMenuStripItemImages).add_Click({ MyCode Here })

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out how to do this... Instead of just adding Context Menus. I also added as David pointed out the Event Handler.

I replaced:

```
  $contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("Item 1") | Out-Null
  $contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("Item 2") | Out-Null
```

With this:

```
  $contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("Item1", $ContextMenuStripItemImages).add_Click({ MyCode Here })
  $contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("Item2", $ContextMenuStripItemImages).add_Click({ MyCode Here })
```

Works great now.